# Process ram use counting for more than it should be (*not* another post about why a lot of ram is always being used)

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance, task-manager, utilization

I am experiencing something strange regarding RAM usage in Windows 10 64-bit. Currently my task manager is listing the 917 MB of RAM being used by my internet browser as 40% of my total installed RAM when I change the resource value display mode to percent, but I have 4GB of RAM installed. All of my other processes display a similar ratio. in that they appear to have their percent use of RAM being relative to about 2300-2400MB.

This leads me to believe that a large portion of my RAM is unusable or at least is not being currently utilized by Windows 10. However, task manager recognizes my total usable physical memory to be 3.9 GB, and I am running a 64-bit version of windows 10. I know that I should not expect my total amount of RAM in use to be the number used by processes listed in the task manager, but I *do* expect that a usage of 917 MB will be listed as about 23.5% RAM utilization, as that is the percentage of 917 out of 3900. I have been thoroughly scouring the internet on reasons for this and possible fixes, and although I have been able to find explanations for higher than expected RAM usage while idle, why you shouldn't expect your RAM usage to be the sum of what you can see used by processes in task manager, and solutions to problems that are a bit similar to mine, I cannot find much of anything on my exact situation.

What is going on with my RAM usage, and if there is a problem with it how can I fix it? Am I misinterpreting something or is my computer ignoring a large chunk of its RAM? My uneducated guess is that my computer is not accessing its full amount of stored RAM but is somehow still thinking that it has that full amount, and the task manager process RAM use percentage is out of the usable amount. How can I go about having my computer properly use all of my installed RAM?

Comment: If your CPU has an on-chip GPU [APU] then that could account for some of that discrepancy, as the RAM is shared.

Comment: Task Manager can be funny with RAM numbers and how they add up. I'd suggest using a tool like Process Explorer and adding the numbers up from there to see if you still get the inconsistency.